# React js - Add unique key onClick

Tags: reactjs

I am having a problem of how to have a key so that when I click the edit button, Input field must show on row depending on what row I clicked.

The output is when I click edit button, All input fields of the row are showing.

Here is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        editable: false,
};
```

Here is the function that is executing when I click the click button:

```
  edit = () => {
    this.setState({
      editable: true,
    })
  }
```

Here is my loop where I want to put the key

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    withKeys = {
     ...data[i],
     key: i,
     actionIndex: (
     <>
     {this.state.editable ? (
      <span>
        <EditableContext.Consumer>
           {form => (
             <a
               onClick={() => this.save(form, data[i])}
               style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
             >
               Save
             </a>
     )}
     </EditableContext.Consumer>
       <Popconfirm title="Sure to cancel?" onConfirm={this.cancel}>
         <a>Cancel</a>
       </Popconfirm>
     </span>
      ):
     <Button 
      onClick={this.edit}
      ghost
      type="primary"
      >
        Edit
    </Button> }
```

How can I add key so that when I click the edit button, input field must show depending on the row where I select the edit button. By the way I am using ant design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an edit index

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
    editIndex: null, // null == no edit
  };
};
```

Update the edit handler to take an index and return the callback function (*this is a Higher Order Function*)

```
edit = editIndex => () => {
  this.setState({ editIndex });
}
```

Then in your render function check the current index to the edit index

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  withKeys = {
   ...data[i],
   key: i,
   actionIndex: (
   <>
     {this.state.editIndex === i ? ( // if editIndex matches current index show edit form
     <span>
     <EditableContext.Consumer>
       {form => (
         <a
           onClick={() => this.save(form, data[i])}
           style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
         >
           Save
         </a>
   )}
   </EditableContext.Consumer>
     <Popconfirm title="Sure to cancel?" onConfirm={this.cancel}>
       <a>Cancel</a>
     </Popconfirm>
   </span>
  ):
  <Button 
   onClick={this.edit(i)} // set callback to enclose index
   ghost
   type="primary"
  >
    Edit
  </Button> }
```

Be sure to set the `editIndex` back to `null` when finished editing.

Comment: It didn't work, the output is when I click the edit button the input fields are not showing

Comment: @Euph I'm not familiar with your forLoop snippet way of rendering/constructing react components, but let's first check that the `edit` handler is correctly setting state to the index you want to edit. Can you try that?

Comment: It now works but for the Save and Cancel text only, So when I click the edit button what is happening is all Input fields are showing but the save and cancel text is now ok and showing depending on which row i clicked. The only problem is the input fields which are all showing when edit button was clicked

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of items, you have to keep `editable` state for each of them. In your code, there is only one `editable` state that controls every element. One way to do it: You can give an id to every element that is being iterated over. Then keep your state like this: `{ editable: <id here> }` When you are reading your data, if the `editable` state matches the current element, then you show the edit form.